# How to Run multiple spring boot application in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm a beginner in gradle need to implement multi-module spring boot rest micro-services

sample source code:[git-hub](https://github.com/ashoksri0/example-multiple-s-run)

when I give a bootRun command

**actual:**
`this task is running only demo1 module so that that rest API I can access`

**expected**

1. Need to run both demo1 and demo2 project in a different port.

Environment: jdk8, spring-boot 2, gradle 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Maven project for running multiple Boot projects in different ports within a single JVM.

https://github.com/rameez4ever/springboot-demo/tree/master/springboot-multi-service-launcher

Changing Maven pom.xml to Gradle build.gradle might be sufficient. Hope this gives some idea.

Comment: I can't find an example in gradle so I tried myself

Comment: Cool. Go ahead.

Comment: the above example is not working with the mvn spring-boot:run command

Comment: So I assume you cloned the repo locally. what is the version of Java and Maven ?Any Exception?

Comment: java version 1.8.0_201  Apache Maven 3.6.0 org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property

Comment: @ashok Did you try running Maven command in the project root directory?